# Return csv file and redirect to same page MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, csv

I have a page with two textboxes for From date and To date and a generate csv file button.

so a user enters both from and to date and click genearte button and csv file gets downloaded to browser.

Now the issue is if there are any validations on the page like date is not valid so have added validation summary for that and it shows up correctly. So if a validation message is shown and then i correct the dates and click generate then it directly returns the file and the validation message still shown up on the page.

Any way to refresh the page after csv file returned or any other way to solve the above issue.

Code is as below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", null, FormMethod.Post, new { novalidate = "novalidate" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Error on page")
    <div >               
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @id="fromDate" })                        
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FromDate)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new {@id = "toDate"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ToDate)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Generate CSV File"/>                    
            </div>
 </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                var response = this.GetCsv(model.FromDate, model.ToDate)                                                                                                         
                return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(response), "text/csv", "Report.csv");                                                    
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Try searching; you can't. An HTTP response delivers either a web page or a file. Download the file through JavaScript and refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some javascript to do this.

The javascript

```
<script>
    function ClearErrorMessages() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("validation-summary-errors");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = "";
        }

        elements = document.getElementsByClassName("field-validation-error");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = "";
        }

        //Removes validation from input-fields
        $('.input-validation-error').addClass('input-validation-valid');
        $('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');
        //Removes validation message after input-fields
        $('.field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid');
        $('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error');           
        //Removes validation summary 
        $('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
        $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
    }
</script>
```

Then add an onclick attribute to the button

```
<input type="submit" onclick="ClearErrorMessages(); return true;" value="Generate CSV File" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no way to refresh validation status use file output, so you need to do twice post...

A. The fastest way is add a download button make it shows after all fields are validated.
B. Another way is use java script to re-post after all fields are validated.

Comment: It would be useful if u can post some code for options A & B.

Comment: For A. 1. Add int IsValid in MyModel  2.add in chtml  <input type="submit" value="Generate CSV File"/>
  @if(model.IsValid == 1)
  {
                 <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Download"/>
  }

Comment: In HttpPost add after if (ModelState.IsValid) :
<code>
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
  model.IsValid = 1
  if(Request.Form["Action"] == "Download" )
  {
                 var response = this.GetCsv(model.FromDate, model.ToDate)                                                                                                         
                 return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(response), "text/csv", "Report.csv");                                                    
  }
        }
</code>